# How much data is considered "too large" for a Hive MAPJOIN job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, amazon-emr

*EDIT: added more file size details, and some other session information.*

I have a seemingly straightforward Hive JOIN query that surprisingly requires several hours to run.

```
SELECT a.value1, a.value2, b.value
FROM a
JOIN b ON a.key = b.key
WHERE a.keyPart BETWEEN b.startKeyPart AND B.endKeyPart;
```

I'm trying to determine if the execution time is normal for my dataset and AWS hardware selection, or if I am simply trying to JOIN too much data.

- Table A: ~2.2 million rows, 12MB compressed, 81MB raw, 4 files.
- Table B: ~245 thousand rows, 6.7MB compressed, 14MB raw, one file.
- AWS: emr-4.3.0, running on about 5 m3.2xlarge EC2 instances.

Records from A always matches one or more records in B, so logically I see that at most 500 billion rows are generated before they are pruned with the WHERE clause.

4 mappers are allocated for the job, which completes in **6 hours**.  Is this normal for this type of query and configuration?  If not, what should I do to improve it?

I've partitioned B on the JOIN key, which yields 5 partitions, but haven't noticed a significant improvement.

Also, the logs show that the Hive optimizer starts a local map join task, presumably to cache or stream the smaller table:

```
2016-02-07 02:14:13 Starting to launch local task to process map join;  maximum memory = 932184064
2016-02-07 02:14:16 Dump the side-table for tag: 1 with group count: 5 into file: file:/mnt/var/lib/hive/tmp/local-hadoop/hive_2016-02-07_02-14-08_435_7052168836302267808-1/-local-10003/HashTable-Stage-4/MapJoin-mapfile01--.hashtable
2016-02-07 02:14:17 Uploaded 1 File to: file:/mnt/var/lib/hive/tmp/local-hadoop/hive_2016-02-07_02-14-08_435_7052168836302267808-1/-local-10003/HashTable-Stage-4/MapJoin-mapfile01--.hashtable (12059634 bytes)
2016-02-07 02:14:17 End of local task; Time Taken: 3.71 sec.
```

What is causing this job to run slowly?  The data set doesn't appear too large, and the "small-table" size is well under the "small-table" limit of 25MB that triggers the disabling of the MAPJOIN optimization.

A dump of the EXPLAIN output is [copied on PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/QDC46n6S) for reference.

My session enables compression for output and intermediate storage.  Could this be the culprit?

```
SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;
SET hive.exec.compress.intermediate=true;
SET mapred.output.compress=true;
SET mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec;
SET io.compression.codecs=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec;
SET io.seqfile.compression.type=BLOCK;
```

Comment: By default the max size of the small table is 25MB

Comment: @KSNidhin: Thanks for pointing that out.  My small table is 14MB in raw size though, so the optimization should still apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this problem is to express the JOIN predicate entirely within the JOIN ON clause, as this is the most efficient way to execute a JOIN in Hive.  As for why the original query was slow, I believe that the mappers just need time when scanning the intermediate data set row by row, 100+ billion times.

Due to Hive only supporting equality expressions in the JOIN ON clause and rejecting function calls that use both table aliases as parameters, there is no way to rewrite the original query's BETWEEN clause as an algebraic expression.  For example, the following expression is illegal.

```
-- Only handles exclusive BETWEEN
JOIN b ON a.key = b.key
AND sign(a.keyPart - b.startKeyPart) = 1.0  -- keyPart > startKeyPart
AND sign(a.keyPart - b.endKeyPart) = -1.0   -- keyPart < endKeyPart
```

I ultimately modified my source data to include every value between `startKeyPart` and `endKeyPart` in a Hive `ARRAY<BIGINT>` data type.

```
CREATE TABLE LookupTable
    key BIGINT,
    startKeyPart BIGINT,
    endKeyPart BIGINT,
    keyParts ARRAY<BIGINT>;
```

Alternatively, I could have generated this value inline within my queries using a custom Java method; the [LongStream.rangeClosed()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html#rangeClosed-long-long-) method is only available in Java 8, which is not part of Hive 1.0.0 in AWS emr-4.3.0.

Now that I have the entire key space in an array, I can transform the array to a table using [LATERAL VIEW](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView) and [explode()](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-explode), rewriting the JOIN as follows.

```
WITH b AS
(
    SELECT key, keyPart, value
    FROM LookupTable
    LATERAL VIEW explode(keyParts) keyPartsTable AS keyPart
)
SELECT a.value1, a.value2, b.value
FROM a
JOIN b ON a.key = b.key AND a.keyPart = b.keyPart;
```

The end result is that the above query takes approximately **3 minutes** to complete, when compared with the original **6 hours** on the same hardware configuration.